# ¿Cómo imprimo directamente desde consola en Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

**Escribí un programa con console.log pero siempre me devuelve undefined**

Escribí la siguiente función:

```
function cualEsMayor(num1,num2,num3){
    if(num1 === num2 && num2 === num3){
        console.log('Los tres numeros son iguales');
    }
    else if(num1 >= num2){
        if(num1>num3? console.log('El numero mas grande es '+num1): console.log('El numero mas grande es: ' + num3));
    }
    else{
        if(num2>num3? console.log('El numero mas grande es '+num2): console.log('El numero mas grande es: ' + num3));
    }
}
```

Esperaba que, al ingresar cualEsMayor(1,2,3) en la consola de Google Chrome me retorne 3, sin embargo me retorna undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Tu código funciona bien. Puedes verlo tu mismo:

```js
function cualEsMayor(num1,num2,num3){
    if(num1 === num2 && num2 === num3){
        console.log('Los tres numeros son iguales');
    }
    else if(num1 >= num2){
        if(num1>num3? console.log('El numero mas grande es '+num1): console.log('El numero mas grande es: ' + num3));
    }
    else{
        if(num2>num3? console.log('El numero mas grande es '+num2): console.log('El numero mas grande es: ' + num3));
    }
}

cualEsMayor(1, 2, 3)
```

Si te refieres a obtener el resultado sin tocar Enter, estás obteniendo `undefined` porque la consola muestra el retorno de la función sin embargo tu función no devuelve nada. Por ejemplo:

```js
function cualEsMayor(num1,num2,num3){
    if(num1 === num2 && num2 === num3){
        return 'Los tres numeros son iguales'
    }
    else if(num1 >= num2){
        return 'El numero mas grande es: ' + (num1 > num3 ? num1 : num3);
    }
    else {
        return 'El numero mas grande es: ' + (num2 > num3 ? num2 : num3);
    }
}

console.log(cualEsMayor(1, 2, 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Como ya bien te respondieron: tu código funciona.

De manera adicional, yo veo que además te enredaste con tu código y los `if`, haciendo que el código sea poco claro.

Solamente tienes que:

- Validar si son todos iguales
- Ver si `num1` es el más grande de todos
- Si no, ver si `num2` es el más grande
- Y en último caso no queda más alternativa que sea `num3`

```js
function cualEsMayor(num1,num2,num3){
    if(num1 === num2 && num2 === num3){
        console.log('Los tres numeros son iguales');
    }
    else if(num1 >= num2 && num1>=num3){
         console.log('El numero mas grande es ' + num1);
    }
    else if(num2 >= num1 && num2>=num3){
         console.log('El numero mas grande es ' + num2);
    }
    else{
         console.log('El numero mas grande es ' + num3);
    }
}
cualEsMayor(7,15,9)
```

Ahora si usas `Math.max` puede resultar más fácil e incluso puedes hacerlo para `n` números

```js
function cualEsMayor(...nums){
  console.log('El numero mas grande es ' + Math.max(...nums));
}

cualEsMayor(7,15,9)
cualEsMayor(7,15,9,33,44,55,7,12,2)
```